# Covariance of an AR(2) model with constant

Tags: time-series, covariance

What is the covariance of an AR(2) model with constant? I have seen a similar question about variance of an AR(2) model but I can't find what the treatment of constant would be.

Apologies I am not sure if this violates community rules, but if they do, please you can point me in the right direction and I would be grateful and on my way.